# Connecting to Windows localhost (IIS) from another computer

Tags: networking, iis-7, windows-vista

I have a Windows Vista laptop running IIS7 for its localhost. On this machine, I can successfully navigate to:

- "http://localhost"
- "http://127.0.0.1"
- "http://mycpuname"

However, I cannot access this localhost website from another computer on the same network. Ideally I would be able to visit "http://mycpuname" (so that I can hard-code a connection), but at this point I might settle for the IP address of the machine (http://192.000.000.xyz)

I've seen similar questions asked here and elsewhere on the internet... but none of the posts seems to fix the issue for me.

Things I've tried:
 - adding exceptions to Windows Firewall to allow TCP ports 80 and 8080
 - disabling Windows Firewall entirely
  - running the "netsh" commands in [this post](http://programming-girl.blogspot.com/2010/03/cant-access-localhost-using-ip-address.html)

Additionally, I am looking at the IP address on the Windows laptop by running "ipconfig" from the command prompt. Oddly enough, trying to access "http://192.000.000.xyz" from the Windows laptop doesn't seem to work...

I have also tried restarting IIS and restarting my machine.

Help?

Comment: This isn't really the right place to ask. This site is for programming problems. Try http://superuser.com/

Comment: Aha, good to know. If I don't figure it out here, I might try asking there... unless there is a good way to transfer the thread across sites.

Comment: I think mods have the power to move it, but that's about it. You might get a good answer here, superuser.com is just specifically for home PC and networking problems, so people there would have more experience with this sort of thing.

Answer (score 8):

Go to windows firewall with advanced security, inbound rules and check and see if world wide web services is enabled. I had this same issue, and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try `netstat -na` - it will show you what IP addresses your web server is listening on.

If it's only listening on `127.0.0.1`, the loopback, you will have to re-configure the web server to listen on all addresses/interfaces (usually either `*.*.*.*`, or `0.0.0.0` in some config file, or just some drop-down in some windows dialog somewhere).

If, on the other hand, `netstat` tells you the web server is listening on `*.*.*.*` or `0.0.0.0`, i.e. all interfaces, then you have to figure out what's blocking the traffic - it's either the local firewall, or something on the path between the two computers.

Comment: OK, so I've done that but I'm not sure I understand what I'm looking for. I see a bunch of lines that indicate some form of 127.0.0.1 in the "Local Address" column, and some form of 0.0.0.0 in the "Foreign Address" column

Comment: You are looking for something that shows `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80` in the "Local Address" and the last column saying "LISTEN". Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms895675.aspx

Answer (score 4):

are you binding to 127.0.0.1?  run below command

```
netstat -an |findstr :80 |findstr LISTEN
```

if it shows 127.0.0.1, you need change IIS listen to 0.0.0.0

Comment: When I run this, I see:
TCP  127.0.0.1:80  0.0.0.0:0  LISTENING

So does that look "correct"?

Comment: Sorry for being dense, but any idea how to go about adding that? I'm looking inside the IIS Manager, and I don't think I understand it clearly enough. I'm trying to add a site binding, but I get the impression that's not the right place.

Comment: So far I am unable to figure this out... I can access the localhost of my Mac from my Vista machine, but not the other way around. As Windows Firewall is disabled, it's got to be something with this IIS Listener

Answer (score -3):

If you want to access your website from any other computer on your local network then you need to simply type your network IP and port. If you want to access it from internet then you need to configure your IP.

Comment: Mechanicum actually the site is down thats why you have the problem. For further process you can use "no-ip" software for dynamic DNS it will solve your problem.